# Flask mp4 file not being displayed in video tag using file path

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application that stores mp4 files in a local directory and save the path in my db. I'm able to access the file user `send_file` provided by flask and download but when I pass the path to the video tag, it's not being displayed. See code below:

Saving the video file: `works fine as expected`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
      form = VideoPicForm()
      if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.vid.name not in request.files:
            flash('No video part specified')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        file = request.files[form.vid.name]
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            filepath = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(filepath)
            video= VideosFiles(description=form.description.data, vidpath=filepath)
            db.session.add(video)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('video uploaded successfully...')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

Accessing from template: ```file not rendering``

```
@app.route('/display')
def display():
    file_data= VideosFiles.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    video= file_data.vidpath
    return render_template('display.html', title='Videos', video=video)
```

In template:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="{{video}}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

But when I download using `send_file`, the video is immediatly downloaded:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    file_data= VideosFiles.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    video= file_data.vidpath
    return send_file(video, as_attachment=True)
```

I'm I missing anything that's causing the video not being rendered in template?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small change in your code. make sure your video store in static folder in flask app structure.

I have the same issue as you, when I store the video in static folder then it's working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="400" controls>
<source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='small.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

And also please use the url_for for html render.

Comment: In this case, how will you associate a user with the uploaded video file in the static folder? That's why I choose to save the file path in the db with foreignkey property to the user model.

Comment: For that case, you can assign the unique file value for each file and store that filename with the reference of user. and also store your file in static as well. So when user ask for the file then get the name of the file from the database and provide that file in the video link.